# Fumbling through and failing at CODE writing. Working code, not working for me

Tags: pic, mplab, xc8

I have installed MPLAB X IDE, XC8 and MPLAB IPE to write the code. Also, I have bought 2 Dev boards for testing the code out on with a PIC16F88. A small chip to get my feet wet. As I looked over many website, I see they offered CODE for testing. Usually an example of push a button, make an LED come on.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000                  // Fosc  frequency for _delay()  library

/*
 * 
 */

#include <xc.h>     /* Hardware device support files. */
#include "16F88_xc8_header.h"


/*
 * 
 */
void main()

{
  OSCCON = 0b01100000;              // Internal frequency 4MHz
  TRISA.F0 = 1;                    //Configure 1st bit of PORTA as input
  TRISA.F1 = 1;                    //Configure 2nd bit of PORTA as input
  TRISA.F2 = 1;
  TRISA.F3 = 1;
  TRISA.F0 = 0;                    //Configure 1st bit of PORTB as output
  TRISB.F1 = 0;                    //Configure 2nd  bit of PORTB as output
  TRISB.F2 = 0;
  TRISB.F3 = 0;
  PORTB = "0x00";                   //All LEDs OFF
  do
  {
    if(PORTA.F0==0)            //If 1st switch is pressed
    {
      __delay_ms(100);    //Switch Debounce
      if(PORTA.F0==0)//If the switch is still pressed
      {
         PORTB.F0 = 1;           //1st LED ON
         __delay_ms(1000);              //1 Second Delay
         PORTB.F0 = 0;           //LED OFF
      }
   }
   if(PORTA.F1 == 0)            //If the 2nd switch is pressed
   {
     PORTB.F1 = 1;           //2nd LED ON
     __delay_ms(1000);              //1 Second Delay
     PORTB.F1 = 0;           //LED OFF
   }
   if(PORTA.F2 == 0)            //If the 3rd switch is pressed
   {
     PORTB.F2 = 1;           //3rd LED ON
     __delay_ms(1000);              //1 Second Delay
     PORTB.F2 = 0;           //LED OFF
   }
   if(PORTA.F3 == 0)            //If 4th switch is pressed
   {
     PORTB.F3 = 1;           //4thLED ON
     __delay_ms(1000);              //1 Second Delay
     PORTB.F3 = 0;           //LED OFF
   }
}

while(1);

}
```

Here is the Website the code came from ... https://microcontrollerslab.com/use-input-output-ports-pic18f452/

I adjusted a few things, like changing PORT letters and errors that came up when trying build. But there are some errors I fail to understand, so I can correct. Here is the build errors ...

```
make -f nbproject/Makefile-default.mk SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory 'F:/PIC Stuff/Basic Scanner PIC16F88/B_SCAN_TEST2.X'
make  -f nbproject/Makefile-default.mk dist/default/production/B_SCAN_TEST2.X.production.hex
make[2]: Entering directory 'F:/PIC Stuff/Basic Scanner PIC16F88/B_SCAN_TEST2.X'
"C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc8\v2.32\bin\xc8-cc.exe"  -mcpu=16F88 -c   -mdfp="C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v5.45/packs/Microchip/PIC16Fxxx_DFP/1.2.33/xc8"  -fno-short-double -fno-short-float -O0 -fasmfile -maddrqual=ignore -xassembler-with-cpp -mwarn=-3 -Wa,-a -DXPRJ_default=default  -msummary=-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file  -ginhx032 -Wl,--data-init -mno-keep-startup -mno-osccal -mno-resetbits -mno-save-resetbits -mno-download -mno-stackcall   -std=c99 -gdwarf-3 -mstack=compiled:auto:auto     -o build/default/production/16F88_TEST2.p1 16F88_TEST2.c 
::: advisory: (2049) C99 compliant libraries are currently not available for baseline or mid-range devices, or for enhanced mid-range devices using a reentrant stack; using C90 libraries
16F88_TEST2.c:28:8: error: member reference base type 'volatile unsigned char' is not a structure or union
  TRISA.F0 = 1;                    //Configure 1st bit of PORTA as input
  ~~~~~^~~
16F88_TEST2.c:30:8: error: member reference base type 'volatile unsigned char' is not a structure or union
  TRISA.F1 = 1;                    //Configure 2nd bit of PORTA as input
  ~~~~~^~~
16F88_TEST2.c:32:8: error: member reference base type 'volatile unsigned char' is not a structure or union
  TRISA.F2 = 1;
  ~~~~~^~~
16F88_TEST2.c:34:8: error: member reference base type 'volatile unsigned char' is not a structure or union
  TRISA.F3 = 1;
  ~~~~~^~~
16F88_TEST2.c:36:8: error: member reference base type 'volatile unsigned char' is not a structure or union
  TRISA.F0 = 0;                    //Configure 1st bit of PORTB as output
  ~~~~~^~~
16F88_TEST2.c:38:8: error: member reference base type 'volatile unsigned char' is not a structure or union
  TRISB.F1 = 0;                    //Configure 2nd  bit of PORTB as output
  ~~~~~^~~
16F88_TEST2.c:40:8: error: member reference base type 'volatile unsigned char' is not a structure or union
  TRISB.F2 = 0;
  ~~~~~^~~
16F88_TEST2.c:42:8: error: member reference base type 'volatile unsigned char' is not a structure or union
  TRISB.F3 = 0;
  ~~~~~^~~
16F88_TEST2.c:44:9: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'volatile unsigned char' from 'char [5]' [-Wint-conversion]
  PORTB = "0x00";                   //All LEDs OFF
        ^ ~~~~~~
16F88_TEST2.c:50:9: error: member reference base type 'volatile unsigned char' is not a structure or union
if(PORTA.F0==0)            //If 1st switch is pressed
   ~~~~~^~~
16F88_TEST2.c:53:16: error: member reference base type 'volatile unsigned char' is not a structure or union
       if(PORTA.F0==0)//If the switch is still pressed
          ~~~~~^~~
16F88_TEST2.c:55:15: error: member reference base type 'volatile unsigned char' is not a structure or union
         PORTB.F0 = 1;           //1st LED ON
         ~~~~~^~~
16F88_TEST2.c:57:15: error: member reference base type 'volatile unsigned char' is not a structure or union
         PORTB.F0 = 0;           //LED OFF
         ~~~~~^~~
16F88_TEST2.c:63:9: error: member reference base type 'volatile unsigned char' is not a structure or union
if(PORTA.F1 == 0)            //If the 2nd switch is pressed
   ~~~~~^~~
16F88_TEST2.c:67:15: error: member reference base type 'volatile unsigned char' is not a structure or union
         PORTB.F1 = 1;           //2nd LED ON
         ~~~~~^~~
16F88_TEST2.c:71:15: error: member reference base type 'volatile unsigned char' is not a structure or union
         PORTB.F1 = 0;           //LED OFF
         ~~~~~^~~
16F88_TEST2.c:78:9: error: member reference base type 'volatile unsigned char' is not a structure or union
if(PORTA.F2 == 0)            //If the 3rd switch is pressed
   ~~~~~^~~
16F88_TEST2.c:82:15: error: member reference base type 'volatile unsigned char' is not a structure or union
         PORTB.F2 = 1;           //3rd LED ON
         ~~~~~^~~
16F88_TEST2.c:86:15: error: member reference base type 'volatile unsigned char' is not a structure or union
         PORTB.F2 = 0;           //LED OFF
         ~~~~~^~~
16F88_TEST2.c:90:9: error: member reference base type 'volatile unsigned char' is not a structure or union
if(PORTA.F3 == 0)            //If 4th switch is pressed
   ~~~~~^~~
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
1 warning and 20 errors generated.
(908) exit status = 1
nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:107: recipe for target 'build/default/production/16F88_TEST2.p1' failed
make[2]: Leaving directory 'F:/PIC Stuff/Basic Scanner PIC16F88/B_SCAN_TEST2.X'
nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:91: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
make[1]: Leaving directory 'F:/PIC Stuff/Basic Scanner PIC16F88/B_SCAN_TEST2.X'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed
make[2]: *** [build/default/production/16F88_TEST2.p1] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 781ms)
```

Comment: In addition to @Mike 's correct answer, `PORTB = "0x00";` is also wrong. You need a number, not a text. Remove the double quotation marks.

Answer (score 2):

All Bit declarations are wrong. Look into the controller header.
e.g. This

```
TRISA.F0 = 1;
```

should be

```
TRISAbits.TRISA0 = 1;  //Bit 0 of PORTA is an input
```

And as @Tagli mentioned there are more errors like:

```
 PORTB = "0x00";
```

Which should be :

```
PORTB = 0x00;
```